# Genymotion ADB is not taking android-sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, genymotion

I am using flutter with android studio on Ubuntu 18.4.

I am trying to run android studio with Genymotion Emulator, so:

I installed genymotion device and run it

and I added genymotion plugin to android studio.

but I could not find the device in genymotion device manager.

[image]

I did some search and found that i must make genymotion ADB use the same SDK of android studio.

I tries to do this but Genymotion gave me an error

"this folder does not contain any Android SDK"

this is the error 
[image]

although this path is same in android studio

[image]

Any help please;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that you have ADB installed.
Check this link for the downloading information [platform-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) and make sure that you have at least one platform installed.

Also, run `flutter doctor` to make sure that you have nothing missing. or else flutter will inform you of the missing dependencies.

Comment: thanks for answering I have run `flutter doctor` then I have fount what was missing, it was SDK tools for android studio, so after add tools, according to [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux) it worked for me.